# JsonMappingException with Arrays of object in spring-jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jackson

i get an error when i try to get an item from my dbms. following error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.pharmawizardcabinet.core.entity.cabinet.Cabinet.listaFarmaci, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: com.pharmawizardcabinet.web.beans.ResponseCabinet[&quot;cabinet&quot;]-&gt;com.pharmawizardcabinet.core.entity.cabinet.Cabinet[&quot;listaFarmaci&quot;])
```

this is my conteiner

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cabinet")
public class Cabinet implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7311927404447970875L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cabinet")
    private List<Farmaco> listaFarmaci;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date setLastModified;

    public Cabinet() {
    }

    @PostPersist
    @PostUpdate
    private void setLastUpdate() {
        this.setLastModified = new Date();
    }

    public List<Farmaco> getListaFarmaci() {
        return listaFarmaci;
    }

    public void setListaFarmaci(List<Farmaco> listaFarmaci) {
        this.listaFarmaci = listaFarmaci;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public Date getSetLastModified() {
        return setLastModified;
    }

    public void setSetLastModified(Date setLastModified) {
        this.setLastModified = setLastModified;
    }

}
```

and this is the item

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Farmaco")
public class Farmaco implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -152536676742398255L;

    public Farmaco() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Column(name = "nome_farmaco")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "codice")
    private String codice;

    @Column(name = "azienda")
    private String azienda;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;

    @Column(name = "scadenza")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date scadenza;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "posologia")
    private Posologia posologia;

    @Column(name = "quantita")
    private Integer quantita;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "note")
    private Note note;

    @ManyToOne(cascade =CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cabinet_id")
    private Cabinet cabinet;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCodice() {
        return codice;
    }

    public void setCodice(String codice) {
        this.codice = codice;
    }

    public String getAzienda() {
        return azienda;
    }

    public void setAzienda(String azienda) {
        this.azienda = azienda;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public Date getScadenza() {
        return scadenza;
    }

    public void setScadenza(Date scadenza) {
        this.scadenza = scadenza;
    }

    public Posologia getPosologia() {
        return posologia;
    }

    public void setPosologia(Posologia posologia) {
        this.posologia = posologia;
    }

    public Integer getQuantita() {
        return quantita;
    }

    public void setQuantita(Integer quantita) {
        this.quantita = quantita;
    }

    public Note getNote() {
        return note;
    }

    public void setNote(Note note) {
        this.note = note;
    }

    public Cabinet getCabinet() {
        return cabinet;
    }

    public void setCabinet(Cabinet cabinet) {
        this.cabinet = cabinet;
    }

}
```

controller is this

```
@Component("managerCabinet")
public class ManagerCabinet {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ManagerCabinet.class);

    @PersistenceContext(name = "pwcabinet-jpa")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public Cabinet getCabinetByUser(User user) {
        logger.debug("[getCabinetByUser] user: " + user.getId());
        return _getCabinetByUser(user);
    }
    private Cabinet _getCabinetByUser(User user) {
        logger.debug("[_getCabinetByUser] user: " + user.getId());
        User find = entityManager.find(User.class, user.getId());
        Query searchCabinetByUser = entityManager.createQuery("Select c from Cabinet c where c.user = :userId", Cabinet.class);
        searchCabinetByUser.setParameter("userId", find);
        Cabinet cabinetSearch = (Cabinet) searchCabinetByUser.getSingleResult();
        cabinetSearch.setUser(find);
        return cabinetSearch;
    }

}
```

but i continue to get error.

if i use the annotation @JsonIgnore in this way

```
@JsonIgnore
public List<Farmaco> getListaFarmaci() {
    return listaFarmaci;
}
```

they works, but i need this information in my result. how i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your method `private Cabinet _getCabinetByUser(User user)` returns the Cabinet instance is then in the  'detached' state, viz. is no longer associated with a persistence context.

When an item is in a detached state non-eagerly fetched associations can longer be accessed.

As the default fetch for @OneToMany is Lazy then in your case

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "cabinet")
private List<Farmaco> listaFarmaci;
```

the field listaFarmaci can no longer be accessed once the loaded Cabinet is detached from the persistence context.

You have various means of dealing with this which would include:

1. Marking the field as being eagerly fetched (not good as will always be eagerly fetched regardless of whether required or not).
2. Forcing the persistence context to remain open until all processing is done typically referred to as the OpenSessionInView pattern (or anti-pattern) depending on your point of view: http://java.dzone.com/articles/open-session-view-design
3. Ensuring all data required for use case is initialized before detachment. There are various ways of achieving this:

Simply accessing the collection is some way e.g. by calling size() but this may not work with all JPA providers.

Specifying FETCH JOIN in your JPQL query which loads the Cabinet (although this has side effects). http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Join_Fetching

Comment: I have modified `_getCabinetByUser(User user)` to check the size of listaFarmaco and it works. Thanks